# <meta name="fragment" content="!"> doesn't work for meteor.js

Tags: meteor, seo, google-search-console

I am using JS Framework Meteor.js. I added spiderable package for server side rendering and manuelschoebel:ms-seo for seo tag. Also i have meta tag  like this:


`<meta name="fragment" content="!">`


In web master tool, when i try to fecth as google , i can't see rendered version of the page. But if i add to the link "?_escaped_fragment_=" , everything works perfect.

Test links are http://11budur.com/ and http://11budur.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answers :

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/bZgWCJTnl08%5B1-25%5D

Web master tool don't rewrite the url.